# Three.js Rendering Issue on iOS Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, three.js, glsl

I've had an issue with a three.js application I'm developing. I can't really describe the issue but [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRZ03.png) does a good job of displaying it. I've tested this on iPhone 6s in both safari and chrome with the same result. On android devices of similar specs I have not had an issue. Is this something I can fix? Or is it just due to the performance requirements of the project.

Comment: Maybe share a picture of how it's supposed to look?

Otherwise your question will most likely be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

From this [Github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9628) discussion, your best option is to see if you are using `FloatType` and change that to `HalfFloatType`. If this doesn't answer your question, update it with examples of where you think it has gone wrong.

Comment: I've noticed that the solution is to change the render texture's precision. My program uses as a THREE.ShaderMaterial; is there any way to specify the material's precision? Also for the record [this](https://i.imgur.com/0vQ4YyE.png) is what the properly rendered scene should look like.

Comment: Here's a link to the specifications: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/ShaderMaterial. I only know the basics of Three and have been using Google to answer your questions. Check Github (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) and the Three.js docs for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread, but in case someone else has a similar problem (like I've had), try adding this snippet at the top of the shader file:

```
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
    precision highp float;
#else
    precision mediump float;
#endif
```